# how to know which field connected to an optionset value group

Tags: dynamics-crm, option-set

I have 2 fields that are connected to the same optionset group, I was asked to change a value number and now I need to know which fields ( in the all system )are connected to the same optionset gourp, I need to know which fields are going to be effected from that change.
Is there a way to know how many or which fields are sharing the same optionSet group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could go to Customization, Then particular Entity and field (global option set).
Click on Show Dependency and it will show you where all this particular filed has been used.

I believe this shall help.

[image]